# What are assemblies?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, assemblies

I have heard many times the word assemblies. Still I don't know what they are and its uses in programming language.

Comment: Different meanings in different languages. What language/platform are you taking about?

Comment: What language/context did you hear it in?

Comment: @Liviu: our proxy is slow, it will take more time than you imagine to load the links clicked from google. our proxy is made in vb.net

Comment: @Liviu M. Community disagrees with that attitude. Please visit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most of your questions are for c# so here is the link for [.net Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly)

> In the .NET framework, an assembly is
>   a compiled  code library for use in
>   deployment, versioning and security.
>   There are two types: process
>   assemblies (EXE) and library
>   assemblies (DLL). A process assembly
>   represents a process which will use
>   classes defined in library assemblies.
>   .NET assemblies contain code in CIL,
>   which is usually generated from a CLI
>   language, and then compiled into
>   machine language at runtime by the CLR
>   just-in-time compiler.

Comment: @Shoban: wikipedia site is not loading. link is not broken. but our proxy is slow. can you please paste the text from wikipedia to a pastebin and send the link.

Comment: wikipedia is blocked? wow!!!! ;-) here is the link : http://pastebin.com/NbZ9uY3Y the formatting is not right. Check wikipedia later.

Comment: @Shoban: so library assemblies (DLL) is added as reference in project. can i add process assemblies (EXE) also as references.

Comment: @Vishnu, no process assemblies are executables, they can not be added as reference though they can dynamically be invoked for execution.

Comment: @Shoban: ok, how to dynamically invoke exe for execution. can i execute a specific function inside exe.

Answer (score 4):

`Assembly` is just a `library` of your `classes`. which you can re-use in your multiple projects so that you do not have to write one class each time for each project.

create one assembly and call it everywhere. thats it.